# Wordpress, redirect domain root to a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

A friend of mine asked for help about his wordpress site. He did his work under `sub.domain.com` and now he'd like to have `domain.com` redirected to it, if possible without showing `sub` in the url bar

This is his domain root `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Following some resources I found, I inserted these two lines after the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it should be so simple but I am doing clearly something wrong...

I tried also commenting the rest, it didn't work

I am not an Apache expert at all, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect **example.com/** to **sub.example.com/** ,you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

^$ matches the root **/** of example.com ,if you want to redirect everything to subdomain ,change the pattern to **^(.*)$** .

Comment: Cool! It works, thanks! Just one last thing, can I hide the subdomain in the url bar in the browser?